# Using a Windows VM from Jenkins through vsphere

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, vsphere

I'm trying to reset-and-launch a Windows VM (in vsphere) during a Jenkins job.  I successfully installed the `vSphere Cloud Plugin`.  I've followed [instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) to setup the Windows machine as a jenkins-mvn-slave, and have it setup to run as a service.

If I click on the button in Jenkins for `Launch Slave Agent`, I can see (in vsphere) that the VM does a `revert snapshot`, and then it does a `power on virtual machine`.  If I attach to the machine, I can see that the Jenkins service starts automatically.  However, back in Jenkins, it tells me that the `Slave did not come online in allowed time`.

Some key settings for my slave:

`Force VM launch: Checked
Wait for VMTools: Not checked
Delay between launch and boot complete: 120
Secondary launch method: Launch slave agents view Java Web Start`

Versions: 

`Jenkins: 1.596.2
vSphere: 5.5.0
Windows: Server 2012 R2 Standard, Build 9600
vSphere plugin: 2.7`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've done a lot of messing around since I posted, but I think the following is what I was doing wrong.  I first got the VM working as a normal slave agent.  Once I had that working, then I tried to setup the same as a vsphere-cloud-slave-agent.  I wasn't realizing that setting up a host as a slave agent is "agent-name specific".

So, I uninstalled the Jenkins service, launched the "vsphere cloud slave agent", logged into the machine, and ran javaws (as specified in the previously mentioned [instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines).

A couple of other gotchas that I encountered (not relevant to the initial post, but maybe relevant to someone who reads this):

1. I originally installed git with a password manager.  Unfortunately, since jenkins jobs aren't interactive, it was hanging on the `git clone` command.  I tried uninstalling and re-installing git, but it didn't fix the problem for whatever user the jenkins slave was running as.  I ended up having to revert to a previous slave image and install git from there.  (I probably could have also figured out what user was running the jenkins slave, and entered the desired password there.)
2. I wanted to run a clean VM for each job.  I never figured out this one.  If I set `Availability` to `Take this slave on-line when in demand and off-line when idle`, that was a good start.  However, if I set the times to 0 and 0, then the machine was constantly rebooting.  If I set the times to 1 and 1, then the machine does mostly what I want, unless there are back-to-back jobs queued to run.

Comment: The hanging on the git clone is likely this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479201/stuck-at-fetch-due-to-authentication-issue/37753202#37753202