# Git clone fails on windows slave

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I am trying to setup a Jenkins windows slave to run some tests suites that will only run on windows. When I git the git clone it hangs for some time and eventually times-out with the below error. I have done quite a bit of research but cannot seem to find the issue. I can login to the box as the user being provided through Jenkins and do a clone directly w/o issue.

> Started by user Bert Alfred Building remotely on
>   windows-jenkins-runner in workspace
>   D:\Jenkins\workspace\selenium-runner
>
> > "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> >     "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config remote.origin.url https://bertalfred@bitbucket.org/marypoppinsco/myproj-tests.git #
> >     timeout=10 Fetching upstream changes from
> >     https://bertalfred@bitbucket.org/marypoppinsco/myproj-tests.git
> >     "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" --version # timeout=10 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
> >     "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" fetch --tags --progress https://bertalfred@bitbucket.org/marypoppinsco/myproj-tests.git
> >     +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
> >     hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from
> >     https://bertalfred@bitbucket.org/marypoppinsco/myproj-tests.git   at
> >     hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:803)  at
> >     hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1063)   at
> >     hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)  at
> >     hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)     at
> >     hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)  at
> >     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
> >       at
> >     jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
> >       at
> >     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
> >       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)  at
> >     hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
> >     hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
> >       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404) Caused by:
> >     hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command ""c:\Program
> >     Files\Git\bin\git.exe" fetch --tags --progress
> >     https://bertalfred@bitbucket.org/marypoppinsco/myproj-tests.git
> >     +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 1: stdout: Process leaked file descriptors. See
> >     http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build
> >     for more information Process leaked file descriptors. See
> >     http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build
> >     for more information
>
> stderr:   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1784)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1513)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
>     at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)    at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)   at
>   hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:88)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  at ......remote call to
>   windows-jenkins-runner(Native Method)     at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1433)
>     at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:797)    at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:131)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.execute(Unknown Source)   at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:801)  ... 11 more
>   ERROR: null Finished: FAILURE

Comment: This seems like a git checkout issue? Are you able to test the git checkout on the Windows slave machine?

Comment: What is GIT_ASKPASS set to? It almost looks as if it's waiting for you to enter a password

Comment: @chenrui As I stated in the question I was able to login as the user I am passing credential for from the slave box and do a successful clone from the command line. this all works great from my linux master and slaves. So I know it is just my unfamiliarity with windows.

Comment: @JoePhillips Unfortunately, I don't even know how to check that?

Comment: the GIT_ASKPASS is in the credentials provider, which you probably can find in `{jenkins_host}/credentials`

Comment: Thanks all. @JoePhillips sent me down the right trail and I found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37753202) Feel free to answer and I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is GIT_ASKPASS set to? It almost looks as if it's waiting for you to enter a password

You basically need to ensure that the credential manager that is set up for Jenkins is automatically supplying the password.

See this answer: [Stuck at fetch due to authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479201/stuck-at-fetch-due-to-authentication-issue/37753202#37753202)