# Detecting an outdated Chocolatey package programmatically

Tags: chocolatey

In my use of Chocolatey to provision Jenkins build nodes, I have a need to perform certain operations before and/or after a `choco upgrade` (e.g., stopping the Jenkins service, or [reconfiguring Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37753202/466874) after installation).

My simplest alternative is to always do these operations regardless of whether an upgrade actually is available/was installed, but ideally I would only do them if it is. I see `choco upgrade <pkg> --whatif` as a way to detect a single outdated package, but short of parsing the output (e.g., looking for the string "is available"), there doesn't look like a simple way to programmatically detect the result. For example, the `%ERRORLEVEL%` after running this command is 0 regardless of whether an upgrade is available.

Is there a better alternative to parsing the output as suggested above, given my scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the output from the `choco outdated` command?

Full information on this can be found here:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-outdated

The command that I think you would be after would be:

`choco outdated -r`

Which would give you the most relevant information, which you could quickly parse to decide if a program that you were interested in was outdated or not.

Comment: This helped me find a solution -- `choco outdated -r | find "<pkg>"`, which returns 0 if it needs updating and 1 if it doesn't.